# Is it possible to put a custom prefix and suffix for a word under cursor in VIM?

Tags: vim

I have many latin words in my TeX document and wan't them to wrap with a special command `\lat{anterior}`. So when I move my cursor in VIM above words, is there an efficent way to add a prefix `\lat{` and suffix `}` to the current word? Ideally with a key binding?

Comment: You should read `:help recording`. You could start recording a macro (`qm`), move to the beginning to the word (possibly with `B`), insert your preffix, them move to the end of the word (possibly `E`), insert the suffix, stop recording (`q`), them move to the next word and execute the macro (`@m`).

Comment: Similar to this post: [Setup a shortcut to replace easily selected strings in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798286/setup-a-shortcut-to-replace-easily-selected-strings-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [tpope/vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin. You can customize it per filetype; see `:help surround-customizing`:

```
autocmd FileType tex let b:surround_45 = "\\lat{\r}"
```

Comment: Now with extra readability: `let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "\\lat{\r}"`

Comment: Use `<c-s>-`. Please read `:h surround` and `:h surround-customizing`